# Allocating a property in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I have the following questions about allocating properties in Objective-C,

if I have the following property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arr;
@synthize arr=_arr;
```

should I allocate this array like:

```
arr=[[NSArray alloc]init];
```

and if I should to, where is the best place to to allocate it?

I know I should release it, but retaining a property will increase its retain count by 1 and allocating it will increase it by another 1, am I right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can allocate the array in two ways:

1. Set the ivar directly with a retained value, like this:

   ```
   _arr = [[NSArray alloc] init];
   ```
2. Set the property with an autoreleased value like this:

   ```
   self.arr = [NSArray array];
   ```

You can do this in your class's init method, although you've not said what superclass this is using so I'm not sure how the init method should look. If it's an NSObject, it will look like this:

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
         self.arr = [NSArray array];
    }
    return self;
}
```

But if it's a UIViewController, you'll need to use initWithNibName:bundle, like this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)bundleOrNil
{
    if ((self = [super itWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:bundleOrNil]))
    {
         self.arr = [NSArray array];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then you need to release it in your dealloc method, like this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [_arr release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

However, you should bear in mind that NSArrays can't be changed once they're created, so you probably either want to initialise it with some objects, like this:

```
self.arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:object1, object2, nil];
```

Or if you want to add objects to it later, you should define it as an NSMutableArray, like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arr;
```

And init it with:

```
self.arr = [NSMutableArray array];
```

That will let you add objects to it later.

By the way, if you get errors in your dealloc method, it probably means that your project is using ARC, which is a new technology in iOS 5 that means you don't need to write release and retain statements any more.

If you aren't using ARC I suggest you do so because it will save you having to worry about this retain/release stuff - any iOS developer who is just starting out now should really use ARC for every project, but because it was only introduced in iOS 5, a lot of the Objective-C books don't cover it.

Comment: Another safe approach to releasing the array in dealloc is `self.arr = nil;` (so long as your property has the retain attribute)

Comment: You could also initialize the array lazily by overriding the getter for the property, though there probably isn't much reason to do that with something this simple.

Comment: @yAak actually it's fine to use self.arr = nil if the property has an assign attribute too. There is a school of thought that says you should avoid calling setter methods in your dealloc though - I won't go into why, as you'll find whole discussion threads on stack overflow of people arguing about it without reaching a consensus :-)

Comment: @David +1 for lazy constructors, but to be honest I think that may be a bit of an advanced concept to introduce at this stage ;-)

Comment: @NickLockwood: Lots of people don't seem to accept the arguments against using property setters in `-dealloc`, but the weight of experience is on the side of eschewing them.

Comment: @Kevin: I'm with you on this, which is why I didn't use the setter in my answer. But there are compelling arguments on both sides that cannot be properly covered in the few lines of a comment. Besides, ARC now makes the whole debate moot anyway ;-)

Comment: Ah, sorry! I haven't read those discussions but I think I understand why it is advisable to not use setters in dealloc!  (I cant edit my original comment now, should I delete it to prevent confusion?)

Comment: That would probably just create more confusion!

Comment: thanks to you all, but retain increase the count by 1, also the alloc so the retain count should be 2, right?

Comment: Yes, that's why when I use the setter to set the are value (self.arr = ...) I don't use alloc but instead use the [NSArray array] constructor, which already returns an autoreleased value (retain count  = 0) so when the setter retains it, the retain count goes to 1. When you set the ivar directly (_arr = ...) it doesn't retain it like calling the setter does, so again, retain count is 1. If you were to say self.arr = [[NSArray alloc] init]; the retain count would be 2.